# Depending on the value of a column in a table Get data from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables `USERS`,`COMPANIES`,`ORGANIZATIONS`

`USERS` contains: USER_ID, USER_OWNER_ID, OWNER_TYPE, USER_NAME

`COMPANIES` contains: COMPANY_ID , COMPANY_NAME

`ORGANIZATIONS` contains: ORGANIZATION_ID, ORGANIZATION_NAME

My requirement is, I have to get the `COMPANIES.COMPANY_NAME` if `USERS.OWNER_TYPE` is 20 and should get the `ORGANIZATIONS.ORGANIZATION_NAME` if `USERS.OWNER_TYPE` is 30

So, I used the following query

```
SELECT US.USER_NAME,
       US.USER_OWNER_ID,
       IF ( 
           US.OWNER_TYPE=20, ORG.ORGANIZATION_NAME, CO.COMPANY_NAME
           ) AS NAME 
  FROM USERS US, 
       COMPANIES CO, 
       ORGANIZATIONS ORG 
 WHERE (US.OWNER_TYPE=20 AND US.USER_OWNER_ID=ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID) 
       OR 
       (US.OWNER_TYPE=30 AND US.USER_OWNER_ID=CO.COMPANY_ID)
```

Problem here is I get repeated records of OWNER_TYPE=30 from OWNERS Table.

Can someone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT us.user_name, 
       us.user_owner_id,
       COALESCE(co.company_name, org.organization_name) AS name
 FROM users us LEFT JOIN companies co
   ON us.user_owner_id = co.company_id
  AND us.owner_type = 30 LEFT JOIN organizations org 
   ON us.user_owner_id = org.organization_id
  AND us.owner_type = 20
```

Sample output:

```
| USER_NAME | USER_OWNER_ID |          NAME |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|     User1 |             1 | Organization1 |
|     User2 |             1 |      Company1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06d66/1)** demo

Comment: **Downvoter** do you care to explain what is it with the down vote?